# how to make raw sql query on strapi v4 typescript

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, strapi

in strapi v3 you could make a raw sql query the following way:

```
const data = await strapi.db.connection.raw(`SELECT * from table`);
```

However, in strapi v4 with typescript enabled, the same line gives the following error:

```
Property 'connection' does not exist on type 'Database'.
```

I've searched the documentation but I could not find how to make a custom sql query in strapi 4 with typescript enabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do that exactly the same:

```
//@ts-ignore
let { rows } = await strapi.db.connection.raw(
    `select id from posts where published_at IS NOT null order by random() limit ${count};`
);
```

sadly the `strapi.db.connection` does yet not support types, for some reason cannot find this issue, but this prop is `Knex` prop i'm not entirely sure but you an somehow cast it to `Knex`

Comment: for strapy v4 use that `strapi.db.connection.context.raw(...)`

Comment: @bora89 its giving me strapy is not defined

Answer (score 0):

```js
const rawBuilder = await strapi.db.connection.raw(
  "SELECT * FROM nameTable;"
);

console.log(rawBuilder, "RESULT:::");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.